# package org.ofbiz.clientmanagementservices does not exist

Tags: java

I have this class that I want to import into another class that is outside the previous class folder.

So, I have a GoogleDriveAPI class, which I want to import to DocumentServices class.
on top of my GoogleDriveAPI class there is this line

```java
package org.ofbiz.ClientManagementServices;
```

but when I try to import it to DocumentServices class with this line below

```java
import org.ofbiz.clientmanagementservices.GoogleDriveAPI;
```

I get this error below,

```java
 error: package org.ofbiz.clientmanagementservices does not exist

  [javac17] import org.ofbiz.clientmanagementservices.GoogleDriveAPI;
```

What might be the problem with my import because I am 100% sure I am doing the right thing?

Comment: Your package is called `org.ofbiz.ClientManagementServices` with a capital M, but you are importing from a package with a small M.

Comment: I have tried your solution @Adam, it doesn't work, same error

Comment: This question isn't answerable with the provided info. Need to know your project structure and/or how you're including this other dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Java packages are cas sensitive.
You should change the import to :

```
import org.ofbiz.ClientManagementServices.GoogleDriveAPI;
```

Comment: @MjdiBO same story bruv error: package org.ofbiz.ClientManagementServices does not exist

Comment: This is java 8, could that be the issue

Comment: Is your GoogleDriveAPI class exist in your classpath ? How are you compiling ?